# Traceback Error

Tags: python, poo, funciones, condiciones, bucles

Hola quería ayuda con un problema recientemente he empezado con POO en python y mi objetivo es programar un videoclub con usuarios pero no se porque cuando los registros me da error
**Este es el código principal**

```
from socio import Socio
from os import system
from videoclub import VideoClub
class Menu:

    def __init__(self,videoclub):
        self.videoclub = videoclub

    def adicionar_socio(self):
        system('cls')
        print('******************************************************************')
        print('*******************     ADICIONAR SOCIO     **********************')
        print('******************************************************************')
        codigo = input('Digite el codigo del nuevo Socio: ')
        nombre = input('Digite el nombre del nuevo Socio: ')
        telefono = input('Digite el telefono del nuevo Socio: ')
        domicilio = input('Digite el domicilio del nuevo Socio: ')
        socio = Socio(codigo, nombre, telefono, domicilio)

        if self.videoclub.adicionar_socio(socio):
            print('******************************************************************')
            print('*******           Socio Ingresado con exito                *******')
            print('******************************************************************')
            input()
        else:
            print('******************************************************************')
            print('*******           Error en el ingreso del socio            *******')
            print('******************************************************************')
            input()



    def mostrar_menu_principal(self):
        while True:
            system('cls')
            print('******************************************************************')
            print('******************************************************************')
            print('****************             VIDEOCLUB            ****************')
            print('******************************************************************')
            print('****************           MENU PRINCIPAL         ****************')
            print('******************************************************************')
            print('******************************************************************')
            print('1. Crear socio')
            print('2. Salir del programa')

            try:
                op = int(input('Digite una opcion a elegir: '))
                print('******************************************************************')

                if op == 1:
                    self.adicionar_socio()
                
                elif op == 2:
                    break
                else:
                    print('******************************************************************')
                    print('* ERROR - HA INGRESADO UNA OPCION INVALIDA')
                    print('******************************************************************')
                    input()
            except ValueError:
                    print('******************************************************************')
                    print('* ERROR - EL DATO INGRESADO ES INVALIDO')
                    print('******************************************************************')
                    input()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    videoclub = VideoClub("ADMIN")
    menu = Menu(videoclub)
    menu.mostrar_menu_principal()


**Este es el código del archivo socio**

    class Socio:

    def __init__(self,codigo,nombre,telefono,domicilio):
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.telefono = telefono
        self.domicilio = domicilio
```

**Este es el codigo de el archivo videoclub(no creo que tenga que ver mucho con el error pero lo dejo por si acaso)**

```
        from socio import Socio

class VideoClub:
    def __init__(self,nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.socios = []
    def buscar_socio(self,codigo):
        for i in range(len(self.socios)):
            if self.socios[i].codigo == codigo:
                return i
        return -1
    def adcionar_socio(self,socio):
        if self.buscar_socio(socio.codigo) == -1:
            self.socios.append(socio)
            return True
        return False
```

**Este es el error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdón si adjunte mucho código pero sentí que si no lo hacia igual y no hacia nada con mi pregunta, ayudenme con este error ya consulte pero no tengo idea de el porque aparece

Comment: Errata. En la clase has escrito `adcionar` en vez de `adicionar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error se encuentra en tu clase VideoClub

```
def adcionar_socio(self,socio):
    if self.buscar_socio(socio.codigo) == -1:
        self.socios.append(socio)
        return True
    return False
```

Deberia de ser

```
def adicionar_socio(self,socio):
    if self.buscar_socio(socio.codigo) == -1:
        self.socios.append(socio)
        return True
    return False
```